# Graph $y = x^2$ in space

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have graphed this equation $y = x^2$ and I got this output:

[image: y=x^2]

Is it correct?

On the other hand, this I what I got in Wolfram|Alpha:

[image: y = x^2 in Wolfram|Alpha]

How do I can analog/compare these two graphs in such a way I can deduce one from the other?

Comment: Seems to be $z = x^2$ in WolframAlpha ($(0,1,0)$ belongs to the graph).

Comment: You should provide your WA input as part of your question.

Comment: As @Abstraction said, the second plot is $z=x^2$, because it does not depend on $y$.

Comment: You can always force certain output in WA by specifying the dependent variable, try $y(x,z)=x^2$ and it will return the graph with z instead of y

Answer (score 2):

Your plot is correct, and I am not sure why Wolfram Alpha is mislabeling axes. You can notice it is really the same graph, just the $y$ and $z$ axes are flipped.

Comment: This is why one should know how to evaluate veracity of software outputs!

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, as you say, you sketch a parabola in $xy$ plane and then imagine an infinite amount of those parabolas pallarel to each other, on planes that range on different height lines $z\in(-\infty,\infty)$ .
note that I believe wolfram had mixed the z and y lines.
Anyhow you can align the axis in any way you desire as long as all 3 lines are perpetual.